# removing row and define row and column as a matrix

Tags: awk

```
ns=4 #number of rows in file1

awk -v s=$ns '{for (i=1;i<=(s-1);i++) if (($1>file1[i,1]) &&($1<file1[i+1,1]) && ($2< (((file1[i+1,1]-file1[i,1])/((file1[i+2,2])-file1[i,2]))*$1)+(file1[i,1]-(((file1[i+1,1]-file1[i,1]))/((file1[i+2,2])-file1[i,2])*file1[i,2])))}' sed  $0 file2 > temp

file1:
{1 2
2 4
3 3
5 5}

file2:
{1.5 3
2.4 4
3.5 4
4.5 3.2}
```

How to remove entire rows of the file2 based on the condition above from file1.
How to define file1 as the matrix, for example, file1[i,1]: ith row and first column of file1.

Comment: the  code is :   awk -v s=$ns '{for (i=1;i<=(s-1);i++)  if (($1>file1[i,1]) && ($1<file1[i+1,1]) && ($2< (((file1[i+1,1]-file1[i,1])/((file1[i+2,2])-file1[i,2]))*$1)+(file1[i,1]-(((file1[i+1,1]-file1[i,1]))/((file1[i+2,2])-file1[i,2])*file1[i,2])))}' sed  $0 file2 > temp        # two files have 2 columns and 4 rows

Comment: the code doesn't make any sense to me.  can you describe in words what you're trying to do?  what is the expected output?  What is `sed` doing at the end?

Comment: I want to remove rows of file2 which is in this condition: if i=1,1.at first choose the first column that is greater than first row and first column of file1  ($1>file1[i,1]) and less than second row and first column of file1 ($1<file1[i+1,1]):  for example: file1[1,1] : means number 1 and file 1[2,1] : means number 2  in file1 .

Comment: 2. then check the second column of these slected number if is in this condition $2< (((file1[i+1,1]-file1[i,1])/((file1[i+2,2])-file1[i,2]))*$1)+(file1[i,1]-(((file1[i+1,1]-file1[i,1]))/((file1[i+2,2])-file1[i,2])*file1[i,2]).  3. at the end if all condition is exist remove all rows. 4. sed use to remove , but I dont know it is correct or not

Comment: I need to know if file1[i,1] is correct or not, how to choose a specific row and column of file1 and compare with numbers in file2.